# What is this math symbol used in a backpropagation tutorial: $\circ$

Tags: notation, backpropagation

I was wondering what this unfilled circle meant. It is in [this](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/implementing-a-neural-network-from-scratch/) tutorial which implements a neural network from scratch. I have posted the specific part for your convenience. It is the line with $\delta_2 = \dots$

[image]

Comment: Please look at the corresponding line of code: `delta2 = delta3.dot(W2.T) * (1 - np.power(a1, 2))`.  Evidently "$\circ$" is being implemented with the `dot` method.

Comment: @whuber I think you meant implemented with the `*` operator.

Comment: @Franck Thank you, yours looks like the correct reading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The symbol $\circ$ is often used to denote [element-wise multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (a.k.a. Hadamard product, Schur product, entrywise product, component-wise multiplication); [$\odot$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03827v1.pdf) and $*$ are common alternatives.

[image]